# Understanding notations in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

What is the difference between these notations  **$\mathbf{\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}}$ and $\mathbf{(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}}$**  in terms of group theory in abstract algebra?

and can anyone give me an example of multiplicative group of non-prime order?

Thanks!

Comment: The multiplicative groups you have up there have order $p-1,$ which is almost never a prime...

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb Z_p^*$?  The notation $\mathbb Z_n$ can mean one of a few things (The cyclic group of order $n$, sometimes the ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, sometimes the $n$-adic numbers).  Depending on that answer, you'll have a different potential relationship.

Comment: @Mark $Z_p^{*}$ multiplicative group of modulo p.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I was trying to say can we have an example of multiplicative group other than $Z_p^{*}$.

Comment: But that is not what you said. You asked for a multiplicative group of nonprime order, and $\Bbb Z_p^\ast$ is a multiplicative group of nonprime order. Or your could take $\Bbb Z_n^\ast$ for other natural numbers $n$, or you could take the $m$th roots of unity in $\Bbb C$ where $m$ is not prime, or you could take positive reals, etc.

Comment: Anyway, $\Bbb Z_n$ is typically shorthand for $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, but is sometimes defined more directly without discussing quotient rings. (Both could refer to either the additive group of the ring of integers mod $n$.)